# Change the local Address into UNC format with address starting from shared folder

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I need to change my local address into UNC format with the address stored in format like:

Computer Name OR Server Name/Shared Folder name and associated path/File Name

**For Example** if address on *local computer* is

```
D:\Workspace\Task Management System\TBMS\src\com\common\dao\fileName.xls
```

and `common` is **shared folder** then *required address* should be like

```
ashish:\common\dao\filename.xls
```

where `ashish` is my **computer name**

Does Java provide some API or class which can implement such kind of conversion, or is there some method through which I can do it?

---

Through net share I got the name for all the shared folder. Won't I be able to get only shared name folder?

My code is:

```
String line = null;
String[] commands = new String[] { "cmd", "/C", "net share" };

Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
InputStream ins = child.getInputStream();
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));

while (!(line = buffReader.readLine()).trim().equals("The command completed successfully."))    
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Is there some way could get details of my shared folders only and not default folders?

Comment: **ashish:\common\dao\filename.xls** is not UNC format, is it?

Comment: it is lyk \\ashish\common\dao\filename.xls
UNC we have \\server\share\file_path

Answer (score 1):

Note that there could be multiple UNC paths for a single file. For example,

`D:\Workspace\Task Management System\TBMS\src\com\common\dao\fileName.xls` can be accessed as `\\ashish\common\dao\filename.xls`

because

`D:\Workspace\Task Management System\TBMS\src\com\common` is shared as `common`

on the machine named `ashish`. If There was another share

`D:\Workspace\Task Management System\TBMS\src\com\common\dao` as `dao`

then it could also be accessed as `\\ashish\dao\filename.xls`

I don't know if you know what is the root of the share. If you don't then you will have to start at the leaf folder and traverse up looking for the first one that is shared.

Next, **how do you find out if a folder is shared?** I do not offhand know of any library that lets you manage windows shared in Java, but there is probably one out there. Even if there isn't it should be easy to parse the output of `net share`, which gives output as follows on Windows XP:

```
Share name   Resource                        Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C$           C:\                             Default share                     
ADMIN$       C:\WINDOWS                      Remote Admin                      
IPC$                                         Remote IPC                        
tmp          c:\tmp
```

You will need to ignore the special shares like `C$`.

Finally, you need to identify the computer name. You can use `System.getenv("COMPUTERNAME")`.

So the pseudocode is:

1. Start with \\ (`\\`)
2. Append Computer Name (`\\ashish`)
3. Append \ (`\\ashish\`)
4. Append shared name of the nearest parent of the file (`\\ashish\common`)
5. Append rest of full file name (`\\ashish\common\dao\filename.xls`)